# Spring Boot WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter does not exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, websecurity

I am new in spring boot, and I am trying to work with JWT.
I follwed many examples and all looks the same.

Before,15 days I make classic auth application with JWT and all works fine, but now I am facing some errors there.

https://github.com/nedim-bajric/basicJWTspring this is a repo of project that I was created before 15 days and it works fine.

Error I gets comming from SecurityConfiguration and it says that is not possible to find WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, and it is not possilbe to @Overide configure method.
Also, there is problem with .antMatchers, it says Cannot resolve method 'antMatchers' in 'ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry'.

There is my config file

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.unze.sis.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import com.unze.sis.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.unze.sis.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

I tried few solutions that I found on stackowerflow, but it doesn't work.

Comment: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated since spring security 5.7. This should solve your problem: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: See also [Stop using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#_stop_using_websecurityconfigureradapter) in the migration guide.